# InternalsVisibleTo , different member variables to different assemblies

Tags: c#, .net, oop, internals, internalsvisibleto

I have a class A_class in Project A.
In class A_class, there is a constructor

```
internal A_class()
 {
  //constructor logic
 }
```

, and a member variable
    internal int A_member;

Now there are two friend assemblies, say Assembly B and Assembly C
I want Assembly B to be able to access only and only A_Class()
I want Assembly C to be able to access only and only A_member
Such that, Assembly B can not access A_member, and
Assembly C can not access A_class()

Is it possible ? Or is there any other alternative for this ?

If i use

```
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("B")]
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("C")]
```

Then both B and C will have access to both A_class() and A_Member, which is not desired

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The attribute InternalsVisibleTo is applied only at the assembly level

> The attribute is applied at the assembly level.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx

You cannot provide differentiated access to the class and member as you desire.